# Issue with Multiple condition if statement Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, pyautogui

I'm writing a program that moves my mouse (using pyautogui lib) if it has not been moved in x amount of seconds. I take the X,Y coordinates twice once at the start and then again after the time delay, then compare both X and Y values against the previous one. I've having issues with my if statement which in theory should do the above but after testing it out it doesn't work as expected. Can anyone suggest any edits I can a make to fix this simple issue.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pyautogui
import time


currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position() #Grabs X,Y mouse position
print("position X1 is", currentMouseX)
print("position Y1 is", currentMouseY)

X1 = currentMouseX
Y1 = currentMouseY

time.sleep(3)

currentMouseX2, currentMouseY2 = pyautogui.position() #Grabs second X,Y position after 3 seconds 
X2 = currentMouseX
Y2 = currentMouseY

print("position X2 is", currentMouseX2)
print("position Y2 is", currentMouseY2)

**if ((X1 == X2) and (Y1 == Y2)):
    print ("!!! MOVE MOUSE !!!")
else:
    print("Mouse does not need to be moved")**
```

FYI: I've left the if statement very simple as I'd like it working before I continue with the program. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: what does the program output for the values ? X1, Y1, X2, and Y2 (cause I am thinking this might some floating point comparison error)

Comment: What the actual problem you're having? Saying it doesn't work as expected is meaningless without saying what it does or what you expect.

Comment: `X2 = currentMouseX` should be `X2 = currentMouseX2` (same with y values) otherwise you are always comparing the initial coords with themselves. Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Saying that your code does not work as expected makes no sense unless you explain what it is supposed to do ALONG WITH WHAT IT IS ACTUALLY DOING.

Having said that, looking at your code I assume your problem is that you always get the result "!!! MOVE MOUSE !!!", even if you did move your mouse.

If you look at your code carfully you will notice that X1 and X2 will always be the same, and Y1 and Y2 also, because you assign them using:

```
X1 = currentMouseX
Y1 = currentMouseY
```

and

```
X2 = currentMouseX
Y2 = currentMouseY
```

without overwriting `currentMouseY`. Instead, you load the second coordinates into `currentMouseX2` and `currentMouseY2`.

In short your code uses way to many unnessecary assignments. Instead, do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pyautogui
import time


prev = pyautogui.position() #Grabs X,Y mouse position
print("position X1 is", prev[0])
print("position Y1 is", prev[1])

time.sleep(3)

after = pyautogui.position() #Grabs second X,Y position after 3 seconds

print("position X2 is", after[0])
print("position Y2 is", after[1])

if (prev == after):
    print ("!!! MOVE MOUSE !!!")
else:
    print("Mouse does not need to be moved")
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than testing for equality, it might be better to test whether the difference is below some threshold value:

```py
moveThresh = 4 # (or suitable small number)
XMove = X2 - X1
YMove = Y2 - Y1
if abs(XMove) < moveThresh and abs(YMove) < moveThresh:
    # treat tiny moves as no move
    print("The mouse is effectively stationary & the cat is bored")
else:
    print("The mouse is moving & the cat is interested")
```

etc.

Unless you're hooking up some interesting hardware, I doubt you'll be moving the mouse - only the mouse pointer.